# Peut-on utiliser le mot "entre" dans cette situation ?

Tags: indications-de-lieu

Est-ce que le cercle se trouve "entre" les deux carrés ?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is out of scope of FSE.

Comment: Quel est le problème @dimitris ? Ce n'est pas une question de mathématique ou quoi, c'est juste un exemple que j'ai fait pour illustrer ma question.

Answer (score 2):

Une petite partie du cercle (et plus précisément ici du disque) se trouve entre les deux carrés :

[image]

Si l'on s'en tient à la définition d'*[entre](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/entre)* qui s'applique ici:

> A l'intérieur d'un espace situé entre deux éléments

la réponse est indéterminée. Le disque n'est pas entièrement à l'extérieur de cet espace et encore moins entièrement à l'intérieur.

La réponse peut aussi dépendre de contraintes éventuelles affectant l'espace disponible entre les deux éléments.

Par exemple les stations de métro Picpus et Bel-Air se situent entre les stations Nation et Daumesnil.

[image]

Comment: Je trouve ca vraiment tiré par les cheveux... même si techniquement correct :-)

Comment: @LaurentS. Je viens de clarifier ma réponse.

Answer (score 1):

Entre : Au milieu ou à peu près au milieu de l’espace qui sépare des personnes ou des choses dont on parle.

Je trouve donc que l'on ne peut pas utiliser entre dans ce contexte.

Comment: Pour être *entre*, il n'est pas nécessaire d'être **au milieu** de l'espace qui sépare des personnes ou des choses, il suffit d'être **dans** cet espace pour être **entre** elles. Quand il y a une éclipse solaire (totale ou partielle), la Lune est **entre** la Terre et le Soleil, mais pas du tout au milieu de l'espace qui sépare la Terre du Soleil puisque la lune est 390 fois plus près de la Terre que du Soleil. Quand l'éclipse est partielle, la Lune n'est pas non plus alignée sur l'axe Terre/Soleil, si c'est ce que tu veux dire par *milieu*.

Comment: Merci pour le commentaire. Bien sûr que je sais ce qui se passe avec la Lune, la Terre et le Soleil (je suis physician:-)!). C'est la définition d'entre que j'ai trouve dans un dictionnaire. Je suis 100% d'accord de la précision que tu as donnée à la définition. Mais je trouve que pour le cas sous question le cercle n'est pas dans l'espace qui se délimite par les deux carrés. D'où ma réponse negative. Il faut que je modifie la définition donnée quand même.

Comment: Quel dictionnaire donne "au milieu" comme définition du mot "entre" ?

Comment: https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/entre (je pense Livio également).

Answer (score 1):

s'il y avait un peu de symétrie je dirais oui on peut dire "le cercle est entre les deux carrés" mais là ce n'est pas du tout le cas, les deux carrés ne cadrent en aucun sens symétriquement le cercle, donc ma propre réponse humble dira **NON** ce n'est pas entre!!